# MS Word macro to parse string located at fixed location in hyperlink address and use string as TextToDisplay for that hyperlink

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink

I am generating a bibliography with a series of hyperlinks, and I would like to parse a string
from the end of the hyperlink to use as the TextToDisplay.

This is a sample hyperlink:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC#######

I would like TextToDisplay to equal PMC#######

This string of length 10 will always be PMC + 7 digits that uniquely identify each reference;
it will always start at position 43.

I found code on this site to create a generic TextToDisplay link,
but in this case I need to have a dynamic TextToDisplay for each unique link.
Here was the code for the generic conversion:

```
Public Sub ChangeHyperlinksText()

    Dim hlink As Hyperlink

    For Each hlink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        hlink.TextToDisplay = "Link"
    Next hlink

End Sub
```

Is it possible to add specific TextToDisplay based on each hyperlink?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is very simple to do.

```
Public Sub ChangeHyperlinksText()
  Dim hlink As Hyperlink
  For Each hlink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    hlink.TextToDisplay = Right(hlink.Address, 10)
  Next hlink
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  Also, learning the syntax now for this type of parsing will be very helpful for similar link text automation in the future.  Best wishes.

Comment: @AndrewWords - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)